# angular 2 type script error - TS2322

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 2 MEAN app project. I am facing below issue in my code.

> error TS2322: Type '{ 'id': string; 'bowlingteam': string;
>   'battingteam': string; }' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
>   Property 'includes' is missing in type '{ 'id': string; 'bowlingteam':
>   string; 'battingteam': string; }'

I have declared a class variable as

```
startMatchInput : Array<any> = [{
       'id' : '',
       'bowlingteam' : '',
       'battingteam' : ''

  }];
```

each of the object I am putting using a function declared in the class. Basically I am forming a single object with keys mentioned in this.startMatchInput variable.

Below is the code which is in a function .

```
function x(){
  var startMatchmasterObj = {
                'id' : '',
                'bowlingteam' : '',
                'battingteam' : ''

          };

startMatchmasterObj.id =  "943974937947";
               startMatchmasterObj.bowlingteam =  "098idsjvlnladfsj";
               startMatchmasterObj.battingteam =  "jzvlzc9a7dfs90as";

 this.startMatchInput = startMatchmasterObj; // here error is coming
}
```

I am assigning my class variable the local variable from the function to access it outside whenever required. But facing above errors.

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated. I am new to angular 2 as well as MEAN stack dev.

Thanks....

Comment: `startMatchInput` is an array, but `startMatchmasterObj` is an object. You can add that object to the array (`this.startMatchInput.push(startMatchmasterObj)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `startMatchInput` is `any[]`.  `startMatchmasterObj` is an object and not an array, so their types are incompatible, hence the error.  So, you can either change the type of startMatchInput to `any`, or you can wrap  `startMatchmasterObj` in an array to assign it.

```
startMatchInput: any = {    // declare it as any, rather than any[]
   'id' : '',
   'bowlingteam' : '',
   'battingteam' : ''
};    

// or...

this.startMatchInput = [startMatchMasterObj];    // wrap in an array
```

Your best choice will depend on how you hope to use this, I guess.